# Added support for .stl file but cannot download

Tags: file-manager

I am trying to add a download link to an `.stl` file after I allowed it in the `mime` variable.
I created a product with a download link and it does work but I want to give a direct access to the file in order to put it on one of my posts.

I searched google and tried many things using the `functions.php` and the `.htaccess` file but none worked.

When I'm trying to directly access the file I am redirected to a 404 page.

This is the code I used to add support for the `.stl` file:

```
function my_myme_types($mime_types){
    $mime_types['stl'] = 'application/vnd.ms-pki.stl'; //Adding stl extension
    $mime_types['rar'] = 'application/x-rar-compressed'; //Adding rar files
    $mime_types['zip'] = 'application/zip   '; //Adding zip files
    return $mime_types;
}

add_filter('upload_mimes', 'my_myme_types', 1, 1);
```

If needed any information please let me know and I will add those.

Comment: Sorry, cannot replicate the issue here. On a fresh WordPress install, with TwentyTwenty theme activated, having the code in `functions.php`, uploaded [a dummy `.stl` file](https://www.ozeki.hu/index.php?owpn=1116) and then on a page, using "Add Media" browsed the `.stl` file and clicked on the "Insert into Page", and this added a link and clicking on the link from front end, it's downloading the file directly ([screenshot](http://prntscr.com/rparas)).

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, I am using Refru theme and plugins: Fast Velocity Minifier, WP Super Cahce and Really Simple SSL.

Comment: We actually can't help if the issue is coming from a third party product like theme or plugin. So we typically suggest our user to [self debug](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tags/debug/info) things first, and come with a lot of valuable debugging information. Question about third party products are off-topic here at the WPSE ([FAQ]).

Comment: Have you confirmed the file is present in the filesystem? Note that the media library is not a file manager, it lists posts of type `attachment`. Can you confirm you're using the normal WP uploader and not something provided by your theme or a plugin?

Comment: @TomJNowell I am using the normal WordPress media uploader. Also, when checking with FTP, the file is there

Comment: "When I'm trying to directly access the file I am redirected to a 404 page." - you mean an URL like /wp-content/uploads/2020/03/filename.stl? If that doesn't work (and the file does exist on disk) then it's your web server that's refusing to serving the file. IIS for example will do this if it doesn't have a mime type for .stl configured in the registry, in HKLM\Software\Classes\.stl . Maybe other web servers do the same?